# Confused about RxJava variable Assignment

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a function that takes in a username String and returns whether or not the user already exists in a MongoDB database. I'm new to the RxJava and Retrofit model, and I'm confused about hwo to assign variables once I subscribe to the Observable object.

```
fun handleUsername(username: String): Boolean {
    var userExists = false

    UserServiceProvider.getUserService().getUserByUsername(username)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : Observer<User> {
                override fun onComplete() {
                    Log.d("\nAppLog: ", "Completed Operation")
                }

                override fun onNext(t: User?) {
                    Log.d("AppLog: ", t.toString())
                    userExists = true
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d("\nERROR: ", "Completed Operation")
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable?) {
                    Log.d("AppLog: ", "Subscribed successfully ")
                }

            })
    return userExists
}
```

The logs work perfectly, and all the calls execute correctly, however the userExists never changes, and stays false. I'm guessing this is because of the anonymous class that I created within the subscribe method, but I still can't pin why.

Comment: Your function returns before the variable is set to true.

Comment: I think I understand. Since the rxjava call is asynchronous, it gets executed on a new thread and so the function would continue and return. How would I change the code to mimic the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 approach is that you subscribe to the Observable that is obtained from `UserServiceProvider.getUserService().getUserByUsername(username)` directly in the function where you actually require the `userExists` boolean value.

There would be code duplication (subscription part) if its required in more than one places. But it would solve your problem.

Comment: However that would be inefficient because I'd be making the call to the server once again :/

Comment: But if I understand correctly, it would also happen in your current code. My suggestion was just to move the subscription to the place of calling code.

Comment: I moved the subscription to where you suggested. Thanks!